# Creating a complex password policy

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a new password policy - we are trying to make users passwords have the following:

Upper and Lower case

Numbers and Special Characters

I am using labels and change them green when a user inputs any of the above.

However the code I have written only changes the labels to green on the first character. it does not recognise text after the first character. So only one will ever be green

```
private void NewPasswordValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
       {             
         if ((new Regex(@"^[A-Z]")).IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text))             
         lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor = Color.Green;                    
      
         if ((new Regex(@"^[a-z]")).IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text))             
         lblLowerCase.ForeColor = Color.Green;          
  
         if ((new Regex(@"^[0-9]")).IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text))             
         lblNumberRequirement.ForeColor = Color.Green;    
          
         if ((new Regex(@"^[!@#$%^&*()_+=\]")).IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text))              
         lblSpecialCharacters.ForeColor = Color.Green;     
       }
```

Comment: if he password should comply with all condition, you combine all if statements to one AND if clause

Comment: You may want to review what `"^"` in a regex does.

Comment: i dont know what the "^" but removing it worked. thank you @teapot418

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of a string. Which is why it was... matching only the beginning of a string.

Comment: Do not assume that just because a password has at least one of each character type it is a safe password. Make sure you only allow passwords that are long enough. How long depends on the level of security you wish to accomplish - the recommendation from [https://www.security.org/](https://www.security.org/how-secure-is-my-password/) is at least 16 chars long.

Comment: I hate when I am forced to put in those special characters and numbers. Better enforce long passwords instead.

Comment: Here is a really secure password: `hello horse happy hero". You don't need to enforce types of characters, just length.

Comment: Regex (and all code, basically) is like a Genie. It absolutely always grants your wishes _exactly and literally_ as you stated them. => ["^ asserts position at start of a line"](https://regex101.com/r/h3LGC2/1)

Comment: I have hidden that part of the code- above this code there is a minimum lenght set to 10 minimum characters. I have also used the other complex criteria cause as that was asked by security

Comment: ...leading to a good portion of user just adding `"_<Initials, one Cap, one uncap><birthyear>"` like `_jD84` to their password which is totally guessable ... _well done, security_.

Comment: @Fildor its annoying I know.. They would like a minimum of 10 characters and all the other criteria

Comment: I feel you. Sometimes you just have to do what you _have to_ do.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's only partly true - if you're using real, complete words, then those kinds of passwords are susceptible to a dictionary attack. Alternating for letters at random or inserting numbers or spacings within the words are a good countermeasure and yield a much stronger password.

Comment: @jhmckimm - XKCD suggests otherwise. https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: @jhmckimm - That's despite dictionaries. Take a 10 character password consisting of random upper and lowercase letters, digits, and 10 symbols (70 choices) or take 4 words from a dictionary of 35,000 words - you have roughly the same number of possibilities - around 2e18 possible passwords. But no-one uses random passwords - unless they use something like LastPass. So if you're expecting people to use symbols etc, then they typically do things like `P@ssw0rd!` which is far more crackable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated source code to help you accomplish what you want to!

```
 private void NewPasswordValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Check for at least one uppercase letter
       if (Regex.IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text, "[A-Z]"))
               lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor = Color.Green;
           else
               lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor = Color.Black;

           // Check for at least one lowercase letter
           if (Regex.IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text, "[a-z]"))
               lblLowerCase.ForeColor = Color.Green;
           else
               lblLowerCase.ForeColor = Color.Black;
       
           // Check for at least one digit
           if (Regex.IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text, "[0-9]"))
               lblNumberRequirement.ForeColor = Color.Green;
           else
               lblNumberRequirement.ForeColor = Color.Black;
       
           // Check for at least one special character
           if (Regex.IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text, "[!@#$%^&*()_+=\\]"))
               lblSpecialCharacters.ForeColor = Color.Green;
           else
               lblSpecialCharacters.ForeColor = Color.Black;
       }
```

PS: You can use red instead of black color!

Comment: Or `lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor = Regex.IsMatch(NewPasswordValue.Text, "[A-Z]") ? Color.Green : Color.Red;`

Comment: this does work but I do get an error for unterminated [] set.. I have to add another ] to close the statement. Then it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
private bool CheckPasswordPolicy(string password)
{
    // Kiểm tra ký tự in hoa
    bool hasUpperCase = new Regex(@"[A-Z]").IsMatch(password);

    // Kiểm tra ký tự in thường
    bool hasLowerCase = new Regex(@"[a-z]").IsMatch(password);

    // Kiểm tra ký tự số
    bool hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]").IsMatch(password);

    // Kiểm tra ký tự đặc biệt
    bool hasSpecialCharacter = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\]]").IsMatch(password);

    // Mật khẩu phải chứa ít nhất một trong các yêu cầu trên
    return hasUpperCase || hasLowerCase || hasNumber || hasSpecialCharacter;
}
```

and:

```
private void NewPasswordValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string password = NewPasswordValue.Text;

    lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor = CheckPasswordPolicy(password) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    lblLowerCase.ForeColor = lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor;
    lblNumberRequirement.ForeColor = lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor;
    lblSpecialCharacters.ForeColor = lblUpperCharacters.ForeColor;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?